# How do I get video to auto-play in A-frame new window?

Tags: aframe

I'm trying to get a video to play automatically, but it's not working and I'm not sure why. I followed the guidelines and have set the video to auto-play. The video works when seeing the live site in split-screen, but it doesn't work when opening the site in a new window or accessing it through the link.

This is the code: https://glitch.com/edit/#!/vr-climate-change-memorial if anyone knows what's wrong, please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

You should not have whitespaces in your `id` nor should there be brackets `(` `)`. It is not invalid but may cause issues, as I believe, happens in your example.

I canged this:

`<video id="debbiesymons (small).mp4" autoplay loop playsinline webkit-playsinline src="..."></video>`

to:

`<video id="debbiesymons_small.mp4" autoplay loop playsinline webkit-playsinline src="..."></video>`

And also this:

`<a-video src="#debbiesymons (small).mp4" position="0 6 -200" scale="12.8 7.2 0"></a-video>`

To:

`<a-video src="#debbiesymons_small.mp4" position="0 6 -200" scale="12.8 7.2 0"></a-video>`

And now the video is playing when the page loads.

#### AudioContext was not allowed to start

> NOTE: Playing sound on iOS — in any browser — requires a physical user interaction. This is a browser limitation, and internal A-Frame events (like fusing cursors) do not count as interaction. Ways to deal with this include using a Begin Experience button to start ambient music, or creating audio sprites with libraries like Howler.js.

[source](https://aframe.io/docs/1.2.0/components/sound.html)

You need any kind of interaction with the page before playing the sound/ video.

A simple button to play the elements would do the trick, you can also make it your starting page. This is not elegant solution but will work for your case:

```
<a-scene background="color: #60860A" foo id="scene" style="display: none">
    //...
</a-scene>
<script>
  function startPlaying(event) {
    document.getElementById("scene").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("debbiesymons_small.mp4").play();
    document.getElementById("sound").components.sound.stopSound();
    document.getElementById("sound").components.sound.playSound();
    event.target.style.display="none";
  }
</script>
<input type="button" onclick="startPlaying(event)" style="width: 100px; height: 100px; position: fixed; top: 100px; left: 100px;">
```

Comment: I made those changes, but the problem is still the same. In a new window, the video is still showing as a black screen. I'm on chrome on windows, maybe that's the problem?

Comment: I remixed your glitch and made it work by just changing what I wrote. I'm also on chrome on windows. Do you get any error in console?

Comment: I see something like this in the console:
`The AudioContext was not allowed to start. It must be resumed (or created) after a user gesture on the page.` That may be the issue. That would mean you need to have some kind of user interaction BEFORE the video can play. That would also explain why it works on split screen as you had interaction with the site

Comment: this is red in my console log: Serving at http://16957e4e128f:3000, http://127.0.0.1:3000, http://172.17.0.45:3000...

Comment: I think the audio context is probably for the sound playing in the background, but if not that would mean that autoplay for video doesn't work?

Comment: I get this warning twice. I suppose one is for audio in the background, and one is for the video (doesn't matter if it's muted - there is probably an audio channel still).

Comment: Ahh ok, I see, ill try and make it work by click. Thank you!